# Is it possible to display only first list element in for loop?

Tags: python

```
for x in range(10):
    data = [['Day','Date','Week'], ['Day','Date','Week'], ['Day','Date','Week']]
    print data[:1]
```

Question: Is it possible to display only first list element in for loop?

Comment: Of which list? :) The answer will vary.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry, I mean first list in `data` lists -> `['Day','Date','Week']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To display only the first element**, you can use index 0

```
data = [['Day','Date','Week'], ['Day','Date','Week'], ['Day','Date','Week']]
print data[0]
```

**Output**

```
['Day','Date','Week']
```

You can display that in for loop like this

```
for x in range(10):
    print data[0]
```

**Output**

```
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
['Day', 'Date', 'Week']
```

**To get all the first elements in the inner lists**

```
data = [['Day','Date','Week'], ['Day','Date','Week'], ['Day','Date','Week']]
print [item[0] for item in data]
```

**Output**

```
['Day', 'Day', 'Day']
```

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful. What if I need first list from my `data` lists?

Comment: Can I in `print data[0]` get only first element from my 10 elements?

Comment: Thank you very much. Ok. This return `Day` from `['Day', 'Date', 'Week']`. I mean all this first list `['Day', 'Date', 'Week']` from my 10 lists

Comment: @netman97 I didnt understand. Could you please show the 10 lists?

Comment: In that case, you dont need for loop at all. Remove the for loop and simply say `print data[0]`

Comment: Ok. But overall this is possible?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. What should I use for this?

Comment: You dont have to use anything. Simply do this `print data[0]`